# iPad Air Overheating for developer

Tags: ios, ipad

Some of my application users are running iPad Air. I have had reports lately of the application crashing, but all the crash reports are just giving me the standard crashed in main method. After further investigation, I think the problem might be with the iPad overheating when they are taking photos.

Is there anything as a developer I can do to maybe save data before the application crashes from overheating?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x180591b90 objc_msgSend + 16
1  Foundation                     0x1818e2658 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 428
2  CoreFoundation                 0x180ed1794 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
3  CoreFoundation                 0x180ed1438 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 884
4  CoreFoundation                 0x180eceb4c __CFRunLoopRun + 1520
5  CoreFoundation                 0x180df8c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
6  GraphicsServices               0x1826e0088 GSEventRunModal + 180
7  UIKit                          0x1860da088 UIApplicationMain + 204
8  intelliSPEC21                  0x10009b56c main (AdvancedMain.m:10)
9  libdyld.dylib                  0x1809968b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Where do you take the overheating idea from?

Comment: From the end user.

Comment: Of course, I'm not 100% that is the cause, but according to the end user they can consistently get my application to crash when taking photos and when the iPad is hot.